# Updating Value Where Date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm looking to update the `SOLUTION_ID` where the `CREATED_DATE` is Greater Than or Equal To the given date.

What I have so far is updating all the records in the Table. `CREATED_DATE` has a `smalldatetime` datatype.

```
UPDATE [Database].[dbo].[TB__TABLE]
SET SOLUTION_ID = 1
WHERE CAST(CREATED_DATE AS datetime) >=  2011-05-08
```

Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to quote the date;

```
WHERE CREATED_DATE >= '2011-05-08'
```

(unquoted `2011-05-08` is treated as a mathematical expression that evaluates to 1998)

Answer (score 1):

Casting of column with smalldatetime is not required. Please see below the sample

```
create table #temp
(
    dat smalldatetime,
    Solution_ID int
)

insert into #temp(dat, Solution_ID)values(1, GETDATE())
insert into #temp(dat, Solution_ID)values(2, GETDATE()+1)
insert into #temp(dat, Solution_ID)values(3, GETDATE()+2)

select * from #temp
where dat >= 'Your date'

Update #temp
Set Solution_ID = 4
Where dat >= 'Your date'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE [Database].[dbo].[TB__TABLE]
SET SOLUTION_ID = 1
WHERE CAST(CREATED_DATE AS datetime) >=  '2011-05-08'
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for the cast at all.

And your query won't work exactly as you expect in that 2011 - 5 - 8 = 1998 which in sql server is 22/6/1905...

```
>= '2011-05-08'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the DATEDIFF function

```
DATEDIFF(dd, @GIVEN_DATE, CREATED_DATE) >= 0
```

This will return the number of days difference from your given date and your created date. When the function returns zero or greater, then the created_date is greater than the given date. No need for casting.

```
    UPDATE [Database].[dbo].[TB__TABLE]        
    SET SOLUTION_ID = 1        
    WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, @GIVEN_DATE, CREATED_DATE) >= 0
```